# BitLocker on Windows 10 Home

Tags: encryption, windows, windows-10, bitlocker

If I encrypt a flash drive using BitLocker on a Windows 10 Pro (With BitLocker supported and installed) device and put it in compatible mode, can I enter the key and read/write to and to/from it from a Windows 10 Home device (without BitLocker supported or installed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can unlock and use the device even on Windows 10 Home edition. However, you won't be able to manage the BitLocker.

Also, BitLocker is a part of Windows and is installed on every Windows copy by default.

Whether is it in compatible mode or not is not important in this case (Home/Pro). That would be important if you use older versions of Windows 10 or even older versions of Windows (8.1, 7, ...)